# How to set full height in box-inner div in bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Please help me,

I am using bootstrap-4 and set design but issue is my box-inner div is working fine in desktop with all div same height when i enter larger or small text but real ipad is not full height same column i have attachment screenshot of desktop output and real ipad output please help why not full height all column in real ipad.

**Desktop output screeshot** : [image]

**Real ipad output screenshot** : [image]

```css
.features-box-style {
                padding: 100px 0;
            }
            .features-box-style .box-inner {
                border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
                border-radius: 4px;
                padding-top: 18%;
                padding-bottom: 18%;
                text-align: center;
                height: 100%;
            }
            .features-box-style .box-inner .icon {
                width: 70px;
                height: 70px;
                display: inline-block;
                background-color: #000;
                color: #fff;
                border-radius: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                line-height: 70px;
                font-size: 25px;
                font-weight: bold;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }
            .features-box-style .box-inner .content {
                width: 75%;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="features-box-style">
            <div class="container">                
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 col-md-6 box">
                        <div class="box-inner">
                            <div class="icon">?</div>
                            <div class="small-title">Pixel Perfect Design</div>
                            <p class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been standard dummy. Lorem Ipsum is simply text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been standard dummy. Lorem Ipsum is simply text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been standard dummy.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 col-md-6 box">
                        <div class="box-inner">
                            <div class="icon">?</div>
                            <div class="small-title">Pixel Perfect Design</div>
                            <p class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 col-md-6 box">
                        <div class="box-inner">
                            <div class="icon">?</div>
                            <div class="small-title">Pixel Perfect Design</div>
                            <p class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been standard dummy.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 col-md-6 box">
                        <div class="box-inner">
                            <div class="icon">?</div>
                            <div class="small-title">Pixel Perfect Design</div>
                            <p class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been standard dummy. Lorem Ipsum is simply text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been standard dummy. Lorem Ipsum is simply text of the printing.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Try using `h-100` class in columns

Comment: Post your iOS version ?

Comment: Iam getting correct view when i check using developer version in chrome

Comment: Chrome is working fine but not working in real ipad.

Answer (score 0):

Try out `flexbox` to stretch the `div` elements.

`<div class="col-12 col-lg-3 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch">`

This `align-items-stretch` will fill the remaining space.